# How Do I Use These .dll Files In My Visual Studio Project?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, pdcurses

I am working with a C# version of ncurses called Curses Sharp. So far, I've been following the [instructions](https://curses-sharp.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=windows) on how to properly install it.

Through these instructions, I've been able to generate the following files:

[image]

When I try to add these as project references in Visual Studio 2019, however, only CursesSharp.dll will import. Attempting to import CursesWrapper.dll results in this error:

[image]

This file is necessary for the functioning of CursesSharp. However, I can't find anything online about how to properly import a wrapper into Visual Studio, or what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Attempting to add just CursesSharp resulted in this error:

[image]

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem like you're quite following those instructions, since they describe making a non-DLL build of PDCurses. Maybe describe _exactly_ what you did?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference that library directly. It appears tha `CursesWrapper.dll` is a C++ library that's imported by `CursesSharp.dll` via P/Invoke (native calls). Just reference CursesSharp.dll and you will be fine. The other library just needs to be present, but it is found automatically.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I tried this, but I'm getting an error when I try that. I've included the error in the original post.

Comment: Then I guess the problem is that a dependency of that library is missing (such as the correct C++ runtime library). Try to look at CursesWrapper with a dependency tool. The above message is shown on any error loading the dll, not only when it's physically not there.